# How to solve this R error: In thdim[i] <- `*vtmp*` : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I encountered the warning in the title when I ran the following code and the results also look weird:

```
thdim <- matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=4) 
d <- c(1, 2, 2, 1)
theta <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.75,0.83,0.91,0.1,0.4,1.2,0.6,0.2),ncol=2) 
thetanew <- matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=2) 
thetanew<- cbind(theta, thetanew)
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:4) {
    thdim[i][j] <- thetanew[i][d[j]] 
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks!

Comment: That is a warning though. Can you explain what are you trying to do and what is your expected output? There is probably a better way.

Comment: @RonakShah sure. I was trying to add elements to the thdim 5x4 matrix from the theta 5x2 matrix, for example, when i=1 and j=2, thdim [1][2]=theta[1][d[2]]=theta[1][2] according to the d vector, however, I encountered the error in the title, so I tried to make the theta 5x2 matrix to have the same shape as the thdim 5x4 matrix, so I added zero columns to make it thetanew 5x4 matrix, but the error still exist. I expected the thdim 5x4 matrix to have values in every location, but now only the first column has values from the theta matrix, all other locations are still zeros.

Comment: Can you show how your final `thdim` would look?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I expected the thdim to be row 1: (1, 0.1, 0.1, 1); row 2: (0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5); row 3: (0.75, 1.2, 1.2, 0.75); row 4: (0.83, 0.6, 0.6, 0.83); row 5: (0.91, 0.2, 0.2, 0.91), but what I got is all zeros except column 1 is (1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.83, 0.91)

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for the answer. That is a possible way to get the expected result for this example, but in more complicated cases where the d vector will be more diverse than 1 and 2, following the original code may be a better way. Do you have clues in terms of where the warning comes from and how to get the expected result if using the original code?

Comment: I corrected your original code and also showed a direct option.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you! the problem is solved! I can't believe it's such a small error in the code. I spent hours trying to fix it but didn't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `d` as an index to subset columns from `theta`.

```
thdim <- matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=4) 
d <- c(1, 2, 2, 1)
theta <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.75,0.83,0.91,0.1,0.4,1.2,0.6,0.2),ncol=2) 

theta[, d]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1.00  0.1  0.1 1.00
#[2,] 0.50  0.4  0.4 0.50
#[3,] 0.75  1.2  1.2 0.75
#[4,] 0.83  0.6  0.6 0.83
#[5,] 0.91  0.2  0.2 0.91
```

To correct the `for` loop, we can do :

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  #You can use nrow(thdim) instead of hard coding 5
  for (j in 1:4) {
    # You can use `length(d)` instead of hardcoding 4
    thdim[i, j] <- theta[i, d[j]] 
  }
}
```